# How can I use Web App Manifest and Application Cache at the same time?

Tags: html, single-page-application, html5-appcache, web-app-manifest

I'm trying to build a simple single HTML page that can be launched when offline (on Android, if that matters).

I'm using the [Web App Manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) to give the app a name for adding to the home screen and display fullscreen with no browser chrome. This much works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="manifest" href="mf.webmanifest">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
</head>
...
</html>
```

This does not appear to be cached when offline. Separately, I can make a page which is cached offline using the [application cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="mf.appcache">
<head>
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
</head>
...
</html>
```

However, when I try to combine these two (so I can have an offline-cached page that launches fullscreen), the Web App Manifest is ignored and I only get the offline behaviour as in the second example.

What I ultimately want is a single page that can be added to the home screen, that opens full screen with no browser/OS chrome at all, and is cached for use offline. A solution that works just on Android using Chrome 65 is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) feature provides the same capabilities as the deprecated Application Cache.

MDN has an article on [Using Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) which I found very helpful in implementing what I needed to replace the Application Cache.

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting dilemma! I wonder if you would have better luck using
`<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">` as described by Google. Here's a link to their recommendations for the [Web App Manifest.](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/#launching_a_page_fullscreen_from_home_screen)

The Web App Capable meta tag is primarily for full screen capabilities. If you want caching specifically, I think using the `http-equiv="cache-control"` header tag and its directives is closer to what you're trying to accomplish. Especially since Service workers aren't globally supported yet. I found a decent explanation on HTML caching here on stack: ["How to set HTTP headers for cache-control."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480318/7827888)

Edit: [another user has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27951414/7827888) that Chrome will not honor this tag if a display is set up in the manifest file

Comment: Thanks, I've tried the `<link rel="manifest" ...>` as you described, that was my first example and is how I got fullscreen working. I don't see anything else in Google's recommendations that relate to offline use. The cache-control header might work, but I really want the page to be stored permanently, not just in a cache where it might get discarded. It's frustrating that the features I want seem to work fine separately, but not together.

Comment: No problem, think the only way to really know is to take your project offline. The '.appmanifest' file should already explicitly list the pages and resources you want available offline/ cached. Try it out and let us know!